# Sorting alphabetically by Array Value in Multidimensional Indexed Array After Custom Sort (usort) / Sort Array by Two Values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Original Array:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Light Amethyst
        [description] => color
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Stone
        [description] => base material
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Emerald
        [description] => color
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => Brass
        [description] => base material
    )
```

Applied `usort($terms, "mysort");` via the following function(s)

```
function getSortOrder($c) {
    $sortOrder = array(
        "base material",
        "color"
    );
    $pos = array_search($c['description'], $sortOrder);
    return $pos !== false ? $pos : 99999;
}

function mysort($a, $b) {
    if( getSortOrder($a) < getSortOrder($b) ) {
        return -1;
    }elseif( getSortOrder($a) == getSortOrder($b) ) {
        return 0;
    }else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

This successfully ordered the array by the `$sortOrder` array in the `getSortOrder` function (base material first, and then color)

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Stone
        [description] => base material
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Brass
        [description] => base material
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Light Amethyst
        [description] => color
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => Emerald
        [description] => color
    )
```

Now I am trying to sort this new sorted array by `name` while keeping the previously applied sort order (base material first and then color).

Expected Output:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Brass
        [description] => base material
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Stone
        [description] => base material
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Emerald
        [description] => color
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => Light Amethyst
        [description] => color
    )
```

Normally I could apply a `usort` function like such:

```
usort($people,"sort_name");
function sort_name($a,$b)
{
  return $a["name"] > $b["name"];
}
```

But this is of course messing up the output of the original `description` sort.

How can I sort first by `description` as in the functions above, and then proceed to sort by `name` while keeping the `description` sort in tact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [array_multisort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) to sort your original data in one go to the expected output (sort by description first, then name) like so

```
$data = [
    ['name' => 'Light Amethyst', 'description' => 'color'],
    ['name' => 'Stone', 'description' => 'base material'],
    ['name' => 'Emerald', 'description' => 'color'],
    ['name' => 'Brass', 'description' => 'base material']
];


array_multisort(array_column($data, 'description'), SORT_ASC, array_column($data, 'name'), SORT_ASC, $data);
```

`$data` will now be sorted by `description` first and `name` second.

Comment: Wow! Works perfectly (and without the need of any custom sorting function -- wasn't expecting that) - thank you!